# C struct => ctypes struct ... is this mapping correct?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I'm trying to access two legacy de/compression functions from Python that are written in C and are currently available via a DLL (I have the C source).

The functions are passed a (partially) populated C struct and use this information to either compress or decompress the data in the buffer provided.

This is how the functions are called. I added __cdecl for Python compatibility.

```
// Both functions return 0 on success and nonzero value on failure
int __cdecl pkimplode(struct pkstream *pStr);
int __cdecl pkexplode(struct pkstream *pStr);
```

Here's the pkstream struct as defined in C:

```
struct pkstream {
   unsigned char *pInBuffer;           // Pointer to input buffer
   unsigned int nInSize;               // Size of input buffer
   unsigned char *pOutBuffer;          // Pointer to output buffer
   unsigned int nOutSize;              // Size of output buffer upon return
   unsigned char nLitSize;             // Specifies fixed or var size literal bytes
   unsigned char nDictSizeByte;        // Dictionary size; either 1024, 2048, or 4096
   // The rest of the members of this struct are used internally,
   // so setting these values outside pkimplode or pkexplode has no effect
   unsigned char *pInPos;              // Current position in input buffer
   unsigned char *pOutPos;             // Current position in output buffer
   unsigned char nBits;                // Number of bits in bit buffer
   unsigned long nBitBuffer;           // Stores bits until enough to output a byte
   unsigned char *pDictPos;            // Position in dictionary
   unsigned int nDictSize;             // Maximum size of dictionary
   unsigned int nCurDictSize;          // Current size of dictionary
   unsigned char Dict[0x1000];         // Sliding dictionary used for compdecomp
};
```

This is my attempt at mirroring this struct in Python.

```
# Define the pkstream struct
class PKSTREAM(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('pInBuffer', c_ubyte),
               ('nInSize', c_uint),
               ('pOutBuffer', c_ubyte),
               ('nOutSize', c_uint),
               ('nLitSize', c_ubyte),
               ('nDictSizeByte', c_ubyte),
               ('pInPos', c_ubyte),
               ('pOutPos', c_ubyte),
               ('nBits', c_ubyte),
               ('nBitBuffer', c_ulong),
               ('pDictPos', c_ubyte),
               ('nDictSize', c_uint),
               ('nCurDictSize', c_uint),
               ('Dict', c_ubyte)]
```

I would really appreciate some help with the following questions (which I'm choosing to ask questions on the front-end rather than just 'winging' it, hopefully for obvious reasons):

1. I'm not sure whether to use c_ubyte, c_char or c_char_p for the members of type **unsigned char**. c_ubyte most closely maps to the ctypes for unsigned char (according to the docs, at least), but is actually an ?int/long? in Python.
2. Sometimes the member is a **pointer** to an unsigned char ... would this map to c_char_p? ctypes docs say ALL byte & unicode strings are passed as pointers anyway, so what provisions do I need to make for this?
3. I need to provide pOutBuffer to the function, which should be a pointer to the location of allocated memory to which the function can copy the de/compressed data. I believe I should use create_string_buffer() to create an appropriately sized buffer for this?
4. I also need to know how to define the member **Dict[0x1000]**, which looks (to me) to create a 4096 byte buffer for internal use within the functions. I know my definition is clearly wrong, but don't know how should it be defined?
5. Should the C functions be decorated as __stdcall or __cdecl? (I've been using the latter on some test DLLs as I've worked my way up to this point).

Any feedback would be VERY much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data in the structure is a pointer, you have to declare it as a pointer on the Python side as well.

One way to do that is to use the `POINTER` utility in ctypes - it is an object on a somewhat higher level than `ctypes.c_char_p`  (and not fully compatible with that) - but your code will become more readable. Also, for simulating C arrays, the base ctypes types can be multiplied by a scalar, and the returned object is one that can be used as a C vector of the base type of the same size - (so the Dict field can be defined as bellow, `c_ubyte * 4096`)

Note that while `char` is equivalent to `c_ubyte`, `int` is equivalent to `c_int` instead of `c_uint` and likewise for `long`.

Your structure definition does not state that the pointed to buffers are `const`. If you pass a python string (immutable) and your library tries to alter it you will get errors. Instead you should pass mutable memory that is returned from `create_string_buffer`, initialised by your string.

```
POINTER = ctypes.POINTER
# Define the pkstream struct
class PKSTREAM(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('pInBuffer', POINTER(c_char)),
               ('nInSize', c_int),
               ('pOutBuffer', POINTER(c_char)),
               ('nOutSize', c_int),
               ('nLitSize', c_char),
               ('nDictSizeByte', c_char),
               ('pInPos', POINTER(c_char)),
               ('pOutPos', POINTER(c_char)),
               ('nBits', c_char),
               ('nBitBuffer', c_long),
               ('pDictPos', POINTER(c_char)),
               ('nDictSize', c_int),
               ('nCurDictSize', c_int),
               ('Dict', c_char * 0x1000)]
```

As for (5), I don't know how you should decorate your C functions - use whatever works.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback! Should I be concerned about the fact that all Python 3 strings are UNICODE strings? Will this affect the data that is passed in pInBuffer? I would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks, James.

Comment: @James: In Python 3 you should only pass properly encoded "bytes" objects to-and-from C code - leave the default unicode strings to  Python code only.